# vscode.d.ts could not be installed

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

when I tried to run vscode-install, it would fail to sync vscode.d.ts. The problem seems random, most of our machines could not success, but two of our machines could success.
The error information is as follows:

```
Detected VS Code engine version: ^1.23.0
Error installing vscode.d.ts: Error: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! lispvsext@0.0.1 postinstall: `vscode-install && node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the lispvsext@0.0.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-15T09_28_45_624Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! lispvsext@1.0.8 postinstall: `cd extension && npm install && cd ..`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the lispvsext@1.0.8 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-15T09_28_45_805Z-debug.log
```

Comment: If the machine once vscode-install success, it would success forever, even if delete the node_modules folder and run "npm cache clean -f"

Comment: To the others who encountered the problem: After I change the vscode engines attribtue from "^1.23.0" to "*", the problem has been resolved!!!!

Comment: use "*" to replace the vscode minimal engine version could work, but the extension could not work. the engine version must be provided.

Comment: currently, I found the problem is caused by the node version. In china, if the node version is 8.12.0, it could not work!  but the node v10.15.0 the vscode.d.ts could be installed!!!!
in American machine, both node version could work well!!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, where the VSCode engine in `package.json` was very old (1.32.0) compared to the current VSCode version (1.64.2). I just updated the engine to the same as my VSCode version in `package.json`:

```json
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^1.64.2"
    },
```

and the tests runner proceeds instead of erroring as before.

Unfortunately, I then got another error:

> Error: Running extension tests from the command line is currently only supported if no other instance of Code is running.

which is a different problem and [a limitation of VSCode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112793) at the moment (1.64.2), though there is [a workaround](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/testing-extension#disabling-other-extensions-while-debugging) for that.